# C# CSVhelper in record delimiters into a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csvhelper

In my CSV the main files are delimited by "," which is normal.  However, within some of my records they are delimited by "|", which is where the problem is.

My Model:

```
public class Inventory
{
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Trim { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Images> ImageURLS { get; set; }
}

public class Images
{
    public string ImageURLS { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller with pseudo code:

I need to read the record, if it sees a |, stop, add to the images list, skip the | and repeat until the end.

```
public ActionResult Inventory()
    {
        var listInventory = new List<Inventory>();
        try
        {

            var reader = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/9712.txt")));
            var invList = reader.GetRecords<Inventory>();

            foreach (var i in invList)
            {
                var vehicle = new Inventory();

                vehicle.Make = i.Make;

                bool split = true;

                while (split)
                {
                    read the string
                    if ("|") then stop.
                    add to vehicle.ImageURLS.Add(string);
                    skip ("|")
                } 
                listInventory.Add(vehicle);
            } 
        }
        catch
        {

        } 
        return View(listInventory);
    }
```

Comment: And what exactly the problem is....??? I reviewed your code and one problem found is, ImageURLS is a collection of type Images, you can not add string into it.

Comment: The problem is I need to split in an individual record something like 1.jpg|2.jpg|3.jpg.  I need to take the 1.jpg, add it to my collection, skip the | and repeat.  I have no idea how to do this within an individual record itself.

Comment: What's your single record contains?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but what you need to do is create a class that inherits from CsvClassMap (as per the CsvHelper docs). In it, you'll need to create a custom converter. It should look something like:

```
public sealed class MappingClass : CsvClassMap<Inventory>
    {
        public MappingClass()
        {
            AutoMap();
            Map(m => m.ImageURLS).ConvertUsing(r => r.GetField("Images")
                .Split(new[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Select(x => new Image{ImageURLS = x}).ToList());
        }
}
```